# How do I update a JComboBox's list from a Document Listener?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, documentlistener

I'm writing a custom JComboBox and whenever the user types something I want to update the drop down menu of my JComboBox. The issue I'm having is that once my DocumentListener sees an update I get an error when I try to add an item to the list.
Here's a basic example of what isn't working:

```
public class InputField extends JComboBox<String> implements DocumentListener{

//when something is typed, gets suggestions and adds them to the popup
@Override
 public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
    try{
        giveSuggestions(ev);
    }
    catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

    }
}
private void giveSuggestions(DocumentEvent ev){
    this.addItem("ok");
}
```

This isn't actually how my program will work (I'm not just going to add OK each time someone types something), but getting this to work would allow me to implement my custom JComboBox the way it needs to work. Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: The error message I get is:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification

Comment: 1) To help us best, please post your complete error message. Is it that you're trying to change the Document from inside the DocumentListener? If so, the API will tell you that you can't do this (not directly), and really shouldn't do this. 2) No, no, no to the empty catch block. 3) I also wonder if what you really want to use is a DocumentFilter. 4) To *really* help us best, create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that shows us what you're trying to do.

Comment: You're trying to change the Document inside its listener, as @HovercraftFullOfEels notes, you should not do this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels OK, I've added the error message. I'm aware that the API says I shouldn't do this, but I'm not trying to edit the text whose changing was alerting the DocumentListener, I'm trying to update the list, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: @hd1 I understand that this is not supposed to be done, although I don't understand why. If this is the case, how should I go about changing the drop down list every time the editable field is changed?

Comment: Again, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org). We don't want to see the whole program, and we are having trouble figuring out what's wrong based on code snippets and descriptions. What I'm asking for is a new program that is small, and that attempts to do nothing more than what you're describing above -- modify a "list" inside of a relevant DocumentListener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        this.addItem("ok");
        // I can never remember the correct way to invoke a class method            
        // from witin and anonymous inner class
        //InputField.addItem("ok"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to fix the problem. I just have one question: for some reason when I type one letter the run() method seems to be called three times: do you know why this is?

Comment: As Hovercraft has mentioned multiple time we can't guess what your code is so you need to post an SSCCE when you find unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I posted the code I posted for a reason, it was quite literally all the code being run besides a simple main statement that put my InputField into a JFrame and made the Frame visible. I didn't include the constructor for the same reason: I thought basic setup was superfluous information.

Comment: How are we supposed to test the code if it doesn't compile and execute?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you are looking for

```
jComboBox2.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
  //add your handling code here:
}   });
```